# dispatch_queue not executing

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

i was undergoing stanford cs 193 p assignment5.The problem is that when i segue a data to destination view controller and use dispatch queue to fetch the data in viewDidLoad method.The  dispatch_async does'nt execute in the destination view controller .Here is my code for View controller A and destination view controller.

view controller A code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

if(!self.places){

    self.spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    self.spinner.center = self.tableView.center;//
    [self.view addSubview:self.spinner];
    [self.spinner startAnimating];


    dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("queue_top_places", NULL);
    dispatch_async(dispatchQueue, ^{

        self.places = [self getRecentPlacesFromFlicker];


        // main queue to load table view data
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


            // load table data
            if(self.tableView.window){

                [self.tableView reloadData];
                [self.spinner stopAnimating];
            }
        });
    });

    dispatch_release(dispatchQueue);

}
// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
 self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = YES;

}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Show Recent Photo List"]){


    int currentRow = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row;

    // set up photo list controller model

    [segue.destinationViewController setPhotosList:[self.places objectAtIndex:currentRow]];

    }               
}
```

Here is my code for destination view controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


// get the current top place name and fetch photos at that place from flicker
if ([self.photosList isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    spinner.center = self.tableView.center;//
    [self.view addSubview:spinner];
    [spinner startAnimating];

    dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue1 = dispatch_queue_create("queue_top_50_photos", NULL);

    dispatch_async(dispatchQueue1, ^{


        self.photosList = [FlickrFetcher photosInPlace:self.photosList  maxResults:50];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            if (self.tableView.window ){

                [self.tableView reloadData];
                [spinner stopAnimating];
            }
        });
    });

   dispatch_release(dispatchQueue1);
}

// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = YES;

self.title = @"50PhotoList";

}
```

The condition ([self.photosList isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) is satisfied checked with a debugger

Comment: Is this condition getting correctly satisfied - `if ([self.photosList isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])` ? Put a breakpoint and see till what line it is working.

Comment: Yes if ([self.photosList isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) condition is satisfied

Answer (score 3):

I was just thinking about this, have you tried running this code in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`? I'd give that a try.

Any reason why you create a new queue for each operation? What if you remove the `dispatch_release` instruction at the end? Maybe your async operation takes longer than the time it gets for your queue to get released.

Try to use a global queue instead of one that you create yourself, one you don't have to release when you're done.

Replace

```
dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue1 = dispatch_queue_create("queue_top_50_photos", NULL);
```

with

```
dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue1 = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
```

and remove the `dispatch_release(dispatchQueue1);`

Comment: try adding a breakpoint inside your block in your second `dispatch_async`, for example, on the `self.photoList = [FlickrFetcher...` line.

Comment: @ Simon Germain   Placed a breakpoint on that line,The debugger is pointing to that line of code in a faded color but code is not executing.

Comment: The debugger stopped at that line?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23678/discussion-between-user1735979-and-simon-germain)

Answer (score 0):

dispatch_async returns immediately and performs the task in background and executes rest of the code in the viewDidLoad or other viewDidAppear methods.

One solution would be to use dispatch_sync which waits for the task to execute and to nest it in dispatch_async like this

```
    dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue1 = dispatch_queue_create("queue_top_50_photos", NULL);

dispatch_async(dispatchQueue1, ^{

      dispatch_queue_t dispatchSyncQueue = dispatch_queue_create("queue_top_50_photos", NULL);

       dispatch_sync( dispatchSyncQueue,^){
          self.photosList = [FlickrFetcher photosInPlace:self.photosList  maxResults:50];
       });
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if (self.tableView.window ){

            [self.tableView reloadData];
            [spinner stopAnimating];
        }
    });

    dispatch_release(dispatchSyncQueue);
});

   dispatch_release(dispatchQueue1);
```